# Xcode Instruments: Analyze Network Traffic

Tags: xcode, networking, android-activity, monitor, instruments

i have a problem with testing my iPhone app: i want a summary of how much network traffic the app needs for a special operation.

I have tried using instruments, but the network activity monitor has no sum of the traffic (and i really neeeeeeed a sum!!!).

So how can i get the sum out of the network activity monitor?

Best regards and thank you,
Christian

Comment: @cschwars what do you mean you you can't get the sum of network traffic? It provides data in/out, can't you just sum that to get the newtwork sum?

Answer (score 0):

Let your iPhone connect to wifi.  Stick a PC on the same LAN.  Now use the PC to run Wireshark and spy the traffic to and from your iPhone.  You have exact number of packets and their sizes.